# How to automatically convert port signals of verilog sub modules using python?

Tags: python, verilog

Let's say there is a TOP module, one logic (logic1) and one test logic (logic2) like in the left picture.

I want to exclude test logic like in the right picture (all verilog form).

[image]

At first, If we suppose all the logics (logic and test logic) are instantiated inside the TOP module,

**The left side of verilog code would be something like this.**
(Let's say a-> blue, b-> yellow, c-> red, d-> green, signal b penetrates test logic)

```
module TOP (

input  a1,
input  b1,
input  c1,
output d1
);
wire   b2;
wire   c2;

logic1 U_logic(
.A (a1),
.B (b2),
.C (c2),
.D (d1),
);

logic2 U_testlogic(
.B    (b2),
.C_IN (c1),
.C    (c2),
);

endmodule
```

**The right side of verilog code would be something like this.**

```
module TOP (

input  a1,
input  b1,
input  c1,
output d1
);

logic1 U_logic(
.A (a1),
.B (b1),
.C (c1),
.D (d1),
);

endmodule
```

If the number of logics and test logics are more than 100, and it is hard to exclude all the test logic manually, How can I deal with this automatically by using Python code (The number of logics and test logics are same)?

**The main goal is to convert port signal of test logic (logic2) to port signal of logic (logic1) and remove test logic. [ex. c2->c1 (.C port signal -> .C_IN port signal), b2->b1 (penetrating signal -> specific input), remove logic2]**

Comment: Aren't you missing `.B_IN (b1)` in `test_logic`?

Comment: Also your question is very broad and also missing details. According to what you show here, the answer is quite simple: parse `U_logic`'s interface and change the ports `x2` to `x1`. The question is what is the real criteria for replacement

Comment: No, but good point. actually I supposed b2 signal connected by other abbreviated instance(When actual TOP module). U can disregard about signal B then if that's gonna be a guestion though.

Comment: As I mentioned and u also said, the criteria gonna be changing port signal * -> *_IN . and remove test logics. And I think u got the point but I found hard to parse it by using python.

Comment: Again, your problem can be very easy, all depending on the perquisites. What I mean by that is if let's say all inputs are as your example `a`, `b`, etc. And the outputs from the test logic are pre/suffixed like let's say `a_test`, `b_test`, etc. then all you need to do is something like `re.sub(r"(w+)_test", "\1", line)` for each line of the interface

Comment: Well mind if I get some examples of what u are saying?

Comment: I still don't understand what about `input  b1`. It is never used in the left case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline of a possible solution is as follows:

```py
import re

with open("test.txt") as in_file, open("output.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if "U_logic" in line:
            out_file.write(line)
            for line in in_file:
                if ");" in line:
                    break
                out_file.write(re.sub(r"(\.\w+\s*\(\w+)2", r"\g<1>1", line))

        elif "U_testlogic" in line:
            for line in in_file:
                if ");" in line:
                    break

        else:
            out_file.write(line)
```

What this does is:

- parse each line of the file.
- Once the declaration of `U_logic` is encountered, start a new loop and:

  - Write each line to the new file until reaching the `);`. The replacement itself is done by the regex shown which can be observed and modified in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xp9eOM/1).
- Once the declaration of `U_testlogic` is reached, simply skip all lines until `);`.
- All other lines are passed on without change to the new file.

---

This is just an outline because there might be many more cases to take in count:

- What if there are parameters to the modules?
- What if the `);` is at the same line as the last port?
- What if the whole instantiation is on one line?
- etc. etc.

I will leave it to you to work-out those details.

Comment: I appreciated your kindness!!  and It did helped a lot. but If the logics are more than 100, Do I have to declare all the logic name like "U_logic" and "U_testlogic" one by one in the code?? (Let's say name of logics have no strict consistency) Can't we just call all the signal of test logic port into logic port signal (*port signal -> *_IN port signal) Thanks again.

Comment: How would you know how to remove them or how to test for `*_IN`? You must have some pattern or else how will this work?

Comment: I am supposing circumstance that name of logic and test logic are same and each one corresponds to another, and their number are same. So, even though the number is over 100, they(one logic and one test logic) can correspond to each other such as U_logic1 /U_testlogic1 , U_logic2 /U_testlogic2 ...etc.

Comment: Well... that would require an initial pass on the file and save each interface to a dict. Then,  have a second pass on the file and replace the main logic interface with the one saved in the dict from the test. Again, this as well will require some pattern to be able to connect between a `logic` module and its corresponding `test` which I still couldn't figure if you have or not

Comment: Ok. This would be the last question, Then If the name of instance is like U_logic1 / U_logic1_test , U_logic2/U_logic2_test ,..and so on, would It be more easier to achieve?? I know u already helped a lot. so If u give any clue supposing situation just like that I will handle it. Thanks again.